# Why is a stop order not triggered when the asking price is reached?

Tags: stocks

I set a stop order to sell some shares at $36 when the market price was around $34. (I bought at $37) The market price rose to $35, with the Ask price reaching $37.9, but the order did not execute. Why? I thought that, when selling, you get the asking price. If I entered a market order in this scenario, would it not sell at $37.9?

Would it have made a difference if I had used a limit order?

UPDATE: My bad, it was a limit order, not a stop.

Comment: You probably wanted a limit order.  A stop order is for initiating a sell once the price goes below some value.  If you want to sell at no less than X then this is a limit order.

Answer (score 4):

You said that when the market price was around $34, you put in a stop order to sell at $36.  That makes no sense, because a sell stop order must have a [stop price below the current market price](http://www.sec.gov/answers/stopord.htm).  I know my broker rejects any sell stop order placed with a stop price above the current market price.  It would make sense if you had placed a limit order to sell at $36.  Are you sure you didn't place a sell limit order at $36?

Then you said the market price rose to $35 and the ask price was $37.9.  That means a buyer and a seller traded shares at $35, and there was another seller who placed a sell limit order at $37.9 - he represented the ask price.  But no buyers bought the shares he was selling at $37.9 - that's why the market price never increased from $35 to $37.9.  If you had a sell limit order at $36, then your order would have represented an ask price of $36, and your shares would have been sold to a buyer willing to pay $36.  If that happened, then the market price would increase to $36.

If you had entered a market order to sell in that scenario, then you would not sell your shares at the ask price of $37.9.  Instead you would sell them at the best bid price, which might have been around $35.  When you enter a market order, you are saying you want to sell at whatever is the best price that a buyer is willing to pay, and the buyers are represented by the bid prices.

Comment: You're right, it was a limit order. Which means my order should have executed. Maybe the 37.9 order was entered after trading hours?

Comment: @alekop Did you ever see the market price go above $36?  If not, then that's why your order didn't execute.  If it did, then yeah, your order should have executed.

Answer (score -1):

If you bought at 37 and put a stop loss order at 36, then in theory ,it should trigger when the market price drops below 36. Can you check with your broker why it didn't execute?